# K-modes clustering: Estimating which features were most impactful on clustering?

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning

I have entirely categorical data (survey results from users), so I've used k-modes clustering to better understand my users.

I'm not an expert at clustering methods at all. Is there a way to known way of estimating the importance of a feature (or combination of features) in deciding which cluster a user falls into?

Comment: You can use [Correlation Coefficient] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_coefficient).

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to counting.

Compute which feature value has the highest probability of predicting a particular cluster. It's a straightforward application of Bayes' formula.

Answer (score 1):

There is an amazing technique available for finding out impact of a different features on the model, it is called Permutation Importance.

To understand how PermuationImportance works please check my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56251253/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-is-permutation-importance-on) answer on stackoverflow.

To see a working example with well explained code, please check [this](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/permutation-importance/notebook) notebook.

Apart from this, if you want to learn how to manually analyse K-Means clustering algorithm please read [this](https://wireilla.com/papers/ijcsa/V2N5/2512ijcsa02.pdf) paper.

Comment: "Link only" answers are generally discouraged because links can become broken or outdated. Please summarize the main points as answers should ideally be self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

What about this: do some manual preprocessing first.

If you have many categorical variables, (Can't be that many for a survey.), for  each one

- order answers by decreasing frequency,
- then lump them together into the say < 10 major responses, and assign the 10th to "other".

Do so for each categorical variable.  Sometimes it will be better to assign, say, only 3 major responses plus "other". Then do one-hot-encoding, (=categorical to numerical using dummy variables) then do simple KMeans clustering and interpret the resulting clusters yourself for plausibility.

If you have only free-text  responses in your survey, or lots of NAs, you have to do even more preprocessing first.

Answer (score -1):

Read about PCA("Principal Component Analysis") and while implementing must standardize data on similar scale.